# Does the Nancy model binder work with properties of type HttpFile?

Tags: model-binding, nancy

The model binder in Nancy (called via the extension methods *Bind* for the type *NancyModule* defined in *Nancy.ModelBinding*) works fine with primitive types (such as *string*), but seems to ignore properties of type *HttpFile*. So if this is my model:

```
class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    // <- successully binds
    public HttpFile Image { get; set; } // <- ignored
}
```

then *Name* will bind successfully, but not *Image*. Examining the *NancyRequest* object on *NancyModule* there is indeed a *Files* property containing the file I want; it's just not getting copied into my model by the binder. Is this supposed to just work, or do I have to write custom code to make this work. If so, how?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No it does not bind on files. You could augment it if you wanted to though